# TCP listening on 0.0.0.0 Vs. listening on 127.0.0.1

Tags: c++, tcp, windows-7, localhost

From client side, I'm trying to connect on `127.0.0.1:843`. When the server is listening to `0.0.0.0:843`, the client gets the connection, but, when server listening on `127.0.0.1:843`, connection refused.
Client and server are on the same machine, and, I see that `127.0.0.1:843` is listening.

The code reference:

```
acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("127.0.0.1"), POLICY_PORT));
```

Vs.

```
acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), POLICY_PORT));
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to mention which OS you are using.

Comment: Check the firewall, windows is famous for that.